# magento multi select category filter

Tags: magento-1.7, ajax

how to multi select the category and filter the result based on selected category.

I need some free extension or some proper guidance to fix this issue.

I am struggling with this issue more than 1 week

Comment: try http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo-6101.html, it will help you filter using multiple filters with ajax support. But it won't support filter products by multiple categories

Comment: But I am in need of selecting multiple categories to filter product is there any other way to do this functionality

Comment: add the code what you have tried so far. It will be easy to answer based on what you have tried

Comment: So far I have listed all category and sub category in left bar added jQuery click event to checkall checkbox of subcategory when main category is clicked but I cant get id of subcategory to pass it in ajax (following error occurs in console TypeError: $(...).childElements is not a function
http://localhost/vidhya/magento/js/varien/js.js
Line 179)

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is, magento isn't build for this.

1. You have to change the behaviour of the filter box to show checkboxes instead of links, then you can think about a button instead of the onclick handler.
2. You have to remove the link list with all the filters or rewrite this too, because magento takes all the filters and removes the one for the one attribute, this means there is a link to remove all category filters
3. You have to rewrite the filtering mechanism, to add possibility for more than one filter, at the moment the attribute filter is a value, no array. This is the most interessting part.

This is a good starting point:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/layered-navigation-but-not-quite/

To change the filter behavior have a look on

`\Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract::_initFilter` and `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category::apply`

And then it should run...

Comment: Please and if you have problems, share the code, open the next question and just ask :)

Comment: I could not find this line in my coding Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract::_initFilter and \Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category::apply

Comment: this isn't code it is a reference to the method _initFilter in the class Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract

Comment: check whether I am going in correct flow I have display category and sub category list as a block in my home page  similar to http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html

Comment: While I am changining in state.phtml doesn't reflect in my front end category navigation I am new to magento so   tell me whether I am going in correct way

Comment: Would you please guide me to fix this issue

Comment: Please open a new question, describe the things you changed compared to magento core so someone can help

Comment: I have create new question but I just add block to display category and sub category in left side bar  similar to http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html

Comment: I find my mistake it is due to display none in css